# MySQL arithmetic subtraction

Tags: mysql, subtraction

I have a table like this:

```
MYSQL 
table_01            tablo_02

Calculated tax      Deductible tax
--------------      ---------------
1200                2100
2305                5200
3250                1200    
2501                3215
```

I want such a result

```
total table_01 - total table_02 = result
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select (
        select sum(calculated_tax)
        from table_01
        ) - (
        select sum(deductible_tax)
        from table_02
        ) as result
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I print this.

$query_tax = "SELECT (SELECT SUM(calculated_tax) FROM table_01) - (SELECT SUM(deductible_tax) FROM tablo_02) AS result";
$result_tax = mysql_query($query_tax) or die(mysql_error());

<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_tax)){  echo  number_format($row['$result_tax)']);
echo "<br />";
 }
?>